# Handling problems with file permissions - PhysFS

Tags: file

My game handles all file access through [PhysicsFS](https://icculus.org/physfs/docs/html/).

(N.B.: PhysicsFS (sometimes called PhysFS) is a file access library, and has nothing to do with game physics;  it just handles opening, reading, and saving files.)

A few times, I've received crash reports from Windows players where my game log shows that PhysFS has been unable to open a user-saved file which we could see in the results of `PHYSFS_enumerateFiles()`, but which generated a "permission denied" error message when I tried to open it using `PHYSFS_openRead()`.

In that situation, my game currently panics and aborts out;  I currently have no game logic for what to do if an attempt to *open* a file fails.

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem myself yet, but my best guess is that the player perhaps first ran the game as an administrator, and now is running it again as a non-administrator, and so the administrator-saved save files are visible but inaccessible to the player's normal, non-administrator account.  Although I guess there could be plenty of other reasons why the OS would generate a "permission denied" error.

My question is this:  What should my game do in this situation?  Are there PhysFS functions I should be calling in advance so that I *know* the file isn't accessible to us, and so the game's UI won't even offer that save to the player or could warn them about the problem in advance, or even maybe give them some advice about how to fix the problem?

Or is just asserting out with an error message an 'acceptable' behaviour when this kind of rare permissions problem happens?  (it doesn't feel to me like this *ought* to be considered 'acceptable', but I'm also not sure how a game would be able to even diagnose the problem, much less fix it!)  Right now, when we have a file open error, we tell Steam that something's wrong with the game's files and that it should re-validate the install, but since this is a *user* file and not an install file, that won't actually help anything.

I'd be quite grateful if folks can suggest better mitigation strategies for this type of error!

Comment: Many months later, I've finally managed to get in contact with an actual player suffering from this problem and we eventually determined what was causing the "permission denied" problem in the first place:  their anti-virus software was refusing to allow the game to read a file it had written earlier!  Adding the file to their anti-virus's whitelist avoided the problem.  This doesn't provide an answer to the "what should we do in this situation" question, but at least now I have a better idea of what the source of the problem was!

Comment: (further details, in case it matters to future readers:  this was most common to happen with some very small screenshots we saved, in jpeg format.  I haven't yet tried changing the file format to see if they're less likely to be flagged by antivirus software)